# Working with Excel 2016 and the length of an audio file eg, 0.004293981 = 0:06:11 (h:mm:ss)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I am working on a spreadsheet that is being used to catalogue a very large number (10,000+) of audio files which can be Wav, Flac, mp3, Ape and ._Pro Tools formats.

The data is supplied to me as a flat worksheet and I am having issues working the track length information for each track.

In the work sheet the length of each track is supplied as 00:06:11 The cell appears to be a custom format of hh:mm:ss. Some tracks can be over an hour in length (02:06:11), some can be just minutes in length (00:06:11) and others just seconds (00:00:11).

I need to remove the extraneous 00 & : dependant on the length of each file like so
02:06:11 becomes 2:06:11, 00:06:11 becomes 6:11 & files less than 60 seconds 00:00:11 become 0:11.
I was given the formula `=IF(TrackDataImport!C2<1/24,"mm:ss","hh:mm:ss")` by Fluff13 on excelforum.com which looks at cell and the returns whether the data in that cell is either minutes & seconds or hours, minutes & seconds. But I have been unable to turn this into a multi-criteria formula that will format the destination cell appropriately. It also does not tell me if it is just “ss”

I know that `=TEXT(TrackDataImport!C2,"hh:mm:ss")` will format the data in which ever cell it is entered into the various formats but I need a formula that will look ahead at the incoming data, decide if its `h:mm:ss, mm:ss or m:ss or ss` (but add the `“0:”` back in so it becomes `“0:11”`) and apply which ever format fits.

I have researched Excel TIME function but I find it confusing at every website seems to use it in regards to physical time passing eg: 12.01 pm and so on. So confusing.

I have an image of worksheet flowchart type sheet here if that helps describe what I wish to achieve better.
[image: Formula Flowchart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this formula works:

```
=IF(HOUR(A1)>0,TEXT(A1,"h:mm:ss"),IF(MINUTE(A1)>0,TEXT(A1,"m:ss"),TEXT(A1,"m:ss")))
```

otherwise -

You can try a UDF as follows:

```
Option Explicit
Function TFormat(tArget As Range) As String

If Hour(tArget) > 0 Then
    If Hour(tArget) > 10 Then
    TFormat = Format(tArget, "hh:mm:ss")
    Else
    TFormat = Format(tArget, "h:mm:ss")
    End If
    Exit Function
End If

If Minute(tArget) > 0 Then
    If Minute(tArget) > 10 Then
    TFormat = Format(tArget, "nn:ss")
    Else
    TFormat = Format(tArget, "n:ss")
    End If
    Exit Function
End If

TFormat = Format(tArget, "n:ss")

End Function
```

[image]

You need to open the developer window (ALT F11 should work). then insert a module and paste the code.
Use as a normal function, if you don't want to keep the function just copy and paste the values afterward and delete the code.

Comment: Note the edit, I added a possible formula solution.

Comment: Justin, Your formula did just what I needed, thank you. In all of my searching online on how to do this I did not find anything so thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A cell custom format style that almost, but not quite, fulfills what you are asking for is

```
[>0,416666] hh:mm:ss;[>0,04166] h:mm:ss; mm:ss
```

It suppresses leading zeroes for the hour-digits, but not for two-digit minutes. The reason is that there can only be three conditions but four would be needed.

The number used in the conditions are 0,416666 ≈ 10/24, equivalent to 10 hours (in need of two hour-digits) and 0,04166 ≈ 1/24, equivalent to 1 hour (in need of one hour-digit).

Comment: Thank you for your reply but as you say it does not fulfill what I am looking for.